# Android Preference - When is createView called in Activity lifecycle to refresh google plus button

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have subclassed preference and it looks like this now:

```
public class gplusPreference  extends Preference {

    public gplusPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {super    (context, attrs, defStyle);}
    public gplusPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {super(context, attrs);}
    public gplusPreference(Context context) {super(context);}

    private PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton;

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

        //do some view stuff ...
        return view;
    }
```

I'd like to know at what point in the preferenceActivity lifecycle onCreateView gets called ? I put break points and onCreateaView is even called after the preferenceActivity's onPostResume is called , thus I'm not sure if its even tied to the life cycle or if its running asynchronously because of the persistent storage it needs to check.

What's happening is I need a call back when the view is ready so I can gain a reference to mPlusOneButton if that helps. I should be using a preferenceFragment but im dealing with legacy code which is already build around PreferenceActivity as the container.

Comment: what is `Preference` ? is it `android.preference.Preference` or `android.support.v7.preference.Preference
` or something else?

Comment: android.preference.Preference

Comment: see [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceGroupAdapter.java#246), `Preference#getView` is [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/preference/Preference.java#491)

Comment: hey thanks for the link but i am asking how its tied to the activity lifecycle.  It seems its not connected but rather connected to the lifecycle of the listview within the preferenceActivity.

Comment: as you can see, it is called inside `ListView`'s adapter, so most likely it is called after onCreate / onStart / onResume, what do you need that knowledge for?

Comment: i am trying to integrate a google plus button inside of a custom preference. Now i have doubts it will be good idea, as the listview keeps calling getview on that cutom preference and i will have to constantly be initalizing google plus button.

Comment: as you can see [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/preference/Preference.java#491) `onCreateView` will be called once per `Preference` and `onBindView` will be called each time that `Preference` needs to be shown

Comment: onBindView is exactly what i was looking for. you can post an offical answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a onbindView to get this done. What i needed to happen was for the google plus button to get refreshed every time the preference is shown on the screen.  So in the onBindView i initialized google plus button. Here is sample code and by the way i know this is bad UX but client needs it:

```
public class gplusPreference  extends Preference {

public gplusPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {super    (context, attrs, defStyle);}
public gplusPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {super(context, attrs);}
public gplusPreference(Context context) {super(context);}

private PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton;

@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

    Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();


    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

    View gplusContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gplus_layout, null, false);



      mPlusOneButton=(PlusOneButton)gplusContainer.findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
//making a container incase i need more share buttons
                ((LinearLayout) view).addView(gplusContainer);

    return view;
}



public void initGPlus(Context context){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD && mPlusOneButton!=null) {

        mPlusOneButton.initialize(context.getString(R.string.play_store_link), Consts.PLUS_ONE_REQUEST);
    }
}

public PlusOneButton getPlusOneButton(){
    return mPlusOneButton;
}
@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    initGPlus(view.getContext());
}
```

}

in PreferenceActivity get the custom preference by calling findpreference and casting it to gplusPreference. then in onResume:

```
     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
 // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus. 
            gplus_pref.initGPlus(this);
        }
```

we have to do that in onResume as the list can be resumed and we need to refresh google plus button or after the google plus dialog returns its also a onResume call and we need to update the button. onBindView is only called when the view is created its not going to be called for onResume's so well had to take care of that case above.

gplus_layout.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/share_buttons_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
        android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        plus:size="standard"
        plus:annotation="inline"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share_gplus"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout for the preference itself called ad_layout.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

this is all how you make a custom preference if you want to google that to understand more on how the layout works.

lastly in preference.xml i'd use it like this:

```
 <myapp.org.myappname.gplusPreference
        android:key="key_gplus"
        android:layout="@layout/ad_layout"/>
```

note: we should not need to check if googleplusClient is on users device anymore, i believe this is taken care of for us now in latest google play services.